# How to have a Zoom API that shows my history

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, zoom-sdk, zoomus

I would like to make a program that automatically fetches my Zoom history. To make this program so far I have used [zoomus](https://github.com/prschmid/zoomus) but I am stuck where on getting the API_KEY and API_SECRET. Does anyone know where to get/make this from?

```py
# Documentation Sample Code

import json
from zoomus import ZoomClient

client = ZoomClient('API_KEY', 'API_SECRET') # This is where I am stuck

user_list_response = client.user.list()
user_list = json.loads(user_list_response.content)

for user in user_list['users']:
    user_id = user['id']
    print(json.loads(client.meeting.list(user_id=user_id).content))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read [Access Credentials](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/credentials#:%7E:text=Zoom%20SDKs%20are%20authenticated%20using,of%20a%20Non%2Dlogin%20user.) by Zoom. Basically you have 2 options:

1. Create SDK/JWT app, and provide the credentials of the app.
2. Use your own credentials. You can fetch the [User Tokens](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/credentials#user-tokens) using the [Users API](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/users/users)